# Use pyQGIS to extract QGIS style as geometry in a DXF

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style, pyqgis-3, dxf

I have a qgis point layer with a complex data driven style:

[image]

This is the style without other layers:

[image]

When exporting the layer as Dxf I would like to also export the style so the symbols are visible in the Dxf.

Is it possible to extract layer symbols/styles as geometry so I can export them as part of my Dxf, too?

This is the style-part of my qml:

```
<renderer-v2 forceraster="0" symbollevels="0" type="singleSymbol" enableorderby="0">
<symbols>
  <symbol alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" type="marker" name="0">
    <layer pass="0" class="SimpleMarker" locked="0">
      <prop k="angle" v="0"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_expression" v=""/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_field" v="Rotation"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_useexpr" v="0"/>
      <prop k="color" v="255,255,255,255"/>
      <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
      <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
      <prop k="name" v="triangle"/>
      <prop k="offset" v="5,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_expression" v="to_string(&quot;Breite_m&quot; /2)||',-'||to_string( 0.5)"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_field" v=""/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_useexpr" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
      <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
      <prop k="outline_width" v="0.4"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="scale_method" v="diameter"/>
      <prop k="size" v="4"/>
      <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="size_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
    </layer>
    <layer pass="0" class="SimpleMarker" locked="0">
      <prop k="angle" v="0"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_expression" v=""/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_field" v="Rotation"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_useexpr" v="0"/>
      <prop k="color" v="255,255,255,255"/>
      <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
      <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
      <prop k="name" v="triangle"/>
      <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_expression" v="to_string(-1*&quot;Breite_m&quot;/2)||',-'||to_string( 0.5)"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_field" v=""/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_useexpr" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
      <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
      <prop k="outline_width" v="0.4"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="scale_method" v="diameter"/>
      <prop k="size" v="4"/>
      <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="size_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
    </layer>
    <layer pass="0" class="SimpleMarker" locked="0">
      <prop k="angle" v="90"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_expression" v="90 + (Rotation)"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_field" v="Rotation"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_useexpr" v="1"/>
      <prop k="color" v="255,0,0,255"/>
      <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
      <prop k="joinstyle" v="miter"/>
      <prop k="name" v="line"/>
      <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_expression" v="to_string(2.5)||',-'||to_string( 0)"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_field" v=""/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_useexpr" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
      <prop k="outline_style" v="dash"/>
      <prop k="outline_width" v="0.4"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="scale_method" v="diameter"/>
      <prop k="size" v="12"/>
      <prop k="size_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="size_dd_expression" v="&quot;Breite_m&quot; +3.5"/>
      <prop k="size_dd_field" v=""/>
      <prop k="size_dd_useexpr" v="1"/>
      <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="size_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
    </layer>
    <layer pass="0" class="FontMarker" locked="0">
      <prop k="angle" v="0"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_expression" v=""/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_field" v="Rotation"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_useexpr" v="0"/>
      <prop k="char_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="char_dd_expression" v=""/>
      <prop k="char_dd_field" v="Klasse"/>
      <prop k="char_dd_useexpr" v="0"/>
      <prop k="chr" v="A"/>
      <prop k="color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
      <prop k="font" v="Arial"/>
      <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
      <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
      <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_expression" v="to_string(&quot;Breite_m&quot; /2)||','||to_string( -1*5)"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_field" v=""/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_useexpr" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
      <prop k="outline_width" v="0"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
      <prop k="size" v="5"/>
      <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="size_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
    </layer>
    <layer pass="0" class="FontMarker" locked="0">
      <prop k="angle" v="0"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_expression" v=""/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_field" v="Rotation"/>
      <prop k="angle_dd_useexpr" v="0"/>
      <prop k="char_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="char_dd_expression" v=""/>
      <prop k="char_dd_field" v="Klasse"/>
      <prop k="char_dd_useexpr" v="0"/>
      <prop k="chr" v="A"/>
      <prop k="color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
      <prop k="font" v="Arial"/>
      <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
      <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
      <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_active" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_expression" v="to_string(-1*&quot;Breite_m&quot; /2)||','||to_string( -1*5)"/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_field" v=""/>
      <prop k="offset_dd_useexpr" v="1"/>
      <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="offset_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
      <prop k="outline_width" v="0"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
      <prop k="size" v="5"/>
      <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
      <prop k="size_unit" v="MapUnit"/>
      <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
    </layer>
  </symbol>
</symbols>
<rotation/>
<sizescale scalemethod="diameter"/>
```

Comment: Which parts of that image are the geometry, and which parts are style?

Comment: @csk: I updated my question

Comment: You could convert the dotted line into a series of short lines, and the triangles into lines or polygons. Use the `geometry by expression` tool. I'm not familiar with the features of DXF format, so I don't know the best way to handle the font markers. If the format supports it, it might make more sense to save the text as an attribute of each triangle feature, and render the attribute as labels in your other program.

Comment: @csk: perhaps it is more a pyQGIS-question: as the dynamic style is rendered in the canvas I guess it should be possible to use pyQGIS to convert the style to a geometry...